# Can I display multiple rows from a selected cell value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building off of a previous question I asked. My problem is I want to create an automated email system that notifies my when a certain cell gets updated relative to a specific person. See Can I automate an email off google sheets based on specific updated columns and rows? for my previous post.

I have the code and it is working great. However, now I am looking to display another Column from the edited row.

Is there a way to display another column from that Row? Like if X12 was edited. Can I also Display B12 and H12. That way it displays my control ID as well as my Control owner?

```
function sendNotification(e){
  var ss = e.source.getSheetByName('Datasheet');
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var cellvalue = e.range.getValue();
  var subject = 'SUBJECT'+ ss.getSheetName();
  var name = ss.getRange(row, 9).getValue(); //get column 9 for current row
  var ControlID = e.col(2).getvalue();


 if (name === 'NAME' && (col === 23 || col === 24 || col === 31 || 
col === 32) === true) {

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "EMAIL",
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: "<br><br>"+
  "The following cell has been updated. <br><br>"+
  "<font size=\"2.5\" color=\"black\"><b> Cell: </b></font>" +
  cell + "<br><br>" + "Control ID: " + col +
  "<br>Update: " + cellvalue + "<br>" + 
  "<br><br>Thank you. <br>"
})
} }
```

So in the email it would state: if X12 was the updated cell

The following control was updated B12. The owner is H12

The updated Cellvalue = X12

I can format how it looks but I can't figure out how to display the same row but a different column of the updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me again - yeah this is totally possible. All you need to do is pass variable `row` to a `getRange()` and use the number of the column you're trying to get the values from.

This script should do the trick.

```
function sendNotification(e){
  var ss = e.source.getSheetByName('Datasheet');
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  var subject = 'SUBJECT'+ ss.getSheetName();
  var name = ss.getRange(row, 9).getValue(); //get column 9 for current row


  if (name === 'NAME' && (col === 23 || col === 24 || col === 31 || col === 32) === true) {
    var control = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue(); //get value for column B in current row
    var owner = ss.getRange(row, 8).getValue();   //get value for column H in current row

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "EMAIL",
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: "The following cell has been updated:<br>"+
      "<font size=\"2.5\" color=\"black\"><b> Cell: </b></font>" + cell + 
      "<br><br>" + "The following control was updated: " + control + ", the owner is: " + owner +
      "<br>Update: " + cellValue + "<br>" + 
      "<br><br>Thank you. <br>"
    });
  } 
}
```

All I've done is added two variables, using `getRange()` like I mentioned earlier:

```
var control = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue(); //get value for column B in current row
var owner = ss.getRange(row, 8).getValue();   //get value for column H in current row
```

Once you've got `var control` and `var owner`, you can use these in your email body, I have also added that to the script above. You can play around with the formatting but I based it off of the template you provided in your question. The email should end up looking something like this (**note: 'b4' and 'h4' are just the examples values I entered into the cell itself**):

[image: Screenshot of email example]

Hope this helps achieve your goal.

Comment: Hey Ross, I thought about commenting in my previous post asking you but I was unsure if it would ping you after I approved your answer. I am new here. Thank you again! I will give it a go.

Comment: Ok, I tested it and it works great. Thanks again, Ross! I couldn't have done it without you. :)